# Renaming Multiple Files Based on Document Text String

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, rename, file-rename

I have already seen that there is something out there called the [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Download.php) but the data files I would like to rename are relatively confidential and so, perhaps unreasonably, I am wary about using it.  As well, I am not certain it will allow me to seek out specific strings in the way I would like it to when it comes to renaming the files.  As such, I was wondering if there is an alternative method that is nearly as good and has some way of ensuring everything remains confidential.  If not, I would be open to hearing about anyone's experiences with Bulk Rename Utility.  Thanks!

EDIT:  I should also note that while I am a novice when it comes to programming I am very open to programming-based solutions.  I should also note that all the files in question are **.html files.**

UPDATE:

Would something like this work?

```
 for file in directory:
 f = fopen(file, 'r')
 line = f.readLine();
 while(line):
  if(line.strip() == '<th style="width: 12em;">Name:</th>'):
   nextline = f.readLine().strip();
   c = nextline.find("</td>")
   name = nextline[4:c]
   os.commandline(rename file to name)
   break
  line = f.readLine()
```

Is there anything I'm missing to make this run well in Python?

UPDATE: Sample html

`<html>  <body>    <h1 style="text-align: right;">[TITLE]</h1>     <div style="font-size: 12pt;">       <div style="float: left;">[NUMBER]</div>       <div style="float: right;">[DATE]</div>       <div style="clear: both;" />     </div>     <hr />     <h3>[INFO]</h3>     <table class="text" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">       <tr>         <th style="width: 12em;">Name:</th>         <td>[NAME]</td>       </tr> </body> </html>`

Comment: `Total Commander` is a file manager that has a very effective Multi-Rename tool.  It can use regular expressions, rename entire trees in one go, and has normal text renaming features.  The author is a trustworthy person IMO, and it's fully functional shareware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excuse me, your question is not clear enough. After read your question several times, I assumed that you want a method (that may be a Windows batch .bat file) that:

- Allows the user to input the search string.
- Process several files with .html extension.
- Look in each file for the value between `<td>` and `</td>` tags that appear in the next line after the first match of the search string, and use it to rename the file.

The Batch file below do such a process:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off

set /P "search=Enter search string: "
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /A-D *.html') do (
   for /F "delims=" %%b in ('cscript //nologo //e:jscript "%~F0" "%%a"') do (
      if "%%b" neq "NoNameFound" (
         ECHO ren "%%a" "%%b"
      ) else (
         echo ERROR: No name found in file "%%a"
      )
   )
)
goto :EOF

@end

var file = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(WScript.Arguments.Item(0)),
    search = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("Process")("search"),
    re = new RegExp(search+".+\n.+<td>(.+)<\/td>",""), result;

if (result = re.exec(file.ReadAll())) {
   WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(result[1]);
} else {
   WScript.Stdout.WriteLine("NoNameFound");
}
file.Close();
```

This is the output with your example data:

```
C:\> test
Enter search string: <th style="width: 12em;">Name:</th>
ren "input.html" "[NAME]"
```

Note that this Batch file just *display* the `ren` command, but it does not execute it! You need to remove the `ECHO` part before `ren` in order to execute it.

If I missed something, please enter a comment with modifications to my specifications.

Comment: Apologies for the ambiguity in the question.  Your answer seems to be what I am looking for.  In the bounty text I mentioned that specifically I was looking for a tkinter GUI to house code that worked similarly to the Python code in the update to my initial question.  I can see how that may not have come across though and I am completely open to a batch solution.  The idea is just to search each file and rename that file for an entire folder.  That is, the folder is selected and each file gets searched and its name replaced.  How would I execute your batch command above?  Thanks!

Comment: Create the Batch file with anyName.bat in the same folder that contain the *.html files. For the test, open a command-line window, `cd` to that folder and run the batch file; the program may be modified to be executed via a double-click if you wish. Sorry, I don't know Python, but the batch file may read the search string via a popup GUI input box if you wish.

Comment: This looks like it will work really well!  I just tried it with ECHO, I'll report back once I've tried it without ECHO.

Comment: One issue that seems to happen upon each run is that it strips the html document format from all explored documents.  When I try to open up any of the documents after I have to select the program to open them and if I open them in a browser it only shows the raw HTML and not the style created by the HTML.

Comment: In addition if I try to run the script in the same folder I receive a "File Not Found" error.

Comment: Please, note that the rename use the new name placed between `<td>` and `</td>` tags _with NO extension_. If the name in the data have NOT .html extension, you must insert such extension in the ren command: `ECHO ren "%%a" "%%b.html"`. This is the type of details that not were clear enough...

Comment: That was definitely the issue, sorry about that.  This seems like it works perfectly, so thank you very much!  I'll let you know if I have any further questions! (P.S. I will award the bounty as soon as it is possible to do so)

Answer (score 1):

Change names using powershell and cmd like a boss just refer the link

http://www.howtogeek.com/111859/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-windows-4-ways-to-rename-multiple-files/

Dont come to conclusion before reading whole page.

Comment: That has some helpful information, but I believe my problem is a bit more complicated and I'm not sure it's possible to solve it this way. Essentially I would like windows to search each file for a keyword and return all characters before two white spaces occur as the file name.