# Renaming Files Based on In-File Strings Using Python

Tags: python

I posted the following code in the [Windows and Rename tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444197/renaming-multiple-files-based-on-document-text-string) and thought it might make more sense to ask about this code here.  Essentially what I am trying to do is use this to rename files based on a particular text string located in the files (the text string in line.strip() below).  I was wondering how I might implement something like this in Python, as this is a rough sketch of how I think it should look but not a complete work.  Is there a best way to fill in the gaps here?  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
for file in directory:
     f = fopen(file, 'r')
     line = f.readLine();
     while(line):
         if(line.strip() == '<th style="width: 12em;">Name:</th>'):
             nextline = f.readLine().strip();
             c = nextline.find("</td>")
             name = nextline[4:c]
             os.commandline(rename file to name)
             break
         line = f.readLine()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the safest way to move the file is to use the [`shutil` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html).  To do this replace replace

```
os.commandline(rename file to name)
```

with

```
shutil.move(os.path.join(directory,file), os.path.join(directory,name))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rename a file with the provided `os` command: (first close the file)

```
f.close()
os.rename(file_name, new_name)
```

Comment: That is good, but it does not adapt to my need to base the name change on an in-file text string from what I can tell.

Comment: well it looks as if you are already able to get the file name from the code you have provided above. I though it was simply a matter of naming.

Comment: Would that resolve the syntax error I get on "os.commandline(rename file to name)"?

Comment: You wouldn't need that line altogether since rename takes care of that.